# JSF SSL Hazzard

Tags: security, jsf, encryption, cryptography, glassfish

In my application it is required that only certain pages need to be secured using SSL so i configured it

```
security-constraint>
<display-name>Security Settings</display-name>
<web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>SSL Pages</web-resource-name>
    <description/>
    <url-pattern>/*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <http-method>GET</http-method>
    <http-method>POST</http-method>
</web-resource-collection>
<user-data-constraint>
    <description>CONFIDENTIAL requires SSL</description>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
```

and added filter

http://blogs.oracle.com/jluehe/entry/how_to_downshift_from_https

but only one hazard is there.i am using it with richFaces. once it goes to HTTPS its not changing the page i mean if i perform post action it doesnt actually happens. but if i do it from the local bmachine's browser it works perfectly from remote browser it stucks with HTTPS its not changing after that

here is my web.xml's snap

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>MyFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>httpPort</param-name>
        <param-value>8080</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Protected resource</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>somePattern</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
  <http-method>POST</http-method>


    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

and some other filters of richfaces.problem is strange.if i try to access the web app from local's machine's browser it works fine but in remote machine's browser once it get into HTTP , all the forms of that page aswell as href stops working.(JSF,facelet is used.)

Answer (score 1):

> In my application it is required that
>   only certain pages need to be secured
>   using SSL so i configured it

Information submitted by the user isn't the only thing you have to worry about. In short what you are trying to accomplish is a vulnerability.

The **only** time this is safe is if the user is no longer authenticated to your application.  By doing this you will be sending your SESSION ID in clear text.  Session id's are used to authenticate browsers,  and if an attacker where to obtain this value though XSS or by Sniffing the line then he won't need a username/password.

This is the most commonly misunderstood part of The OWASP Top 10 2010 [A3-Broken Authentication and Session Management](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A3-Broken_Authentication_and_Session_Management)

Comment: didn't get you Rook.  
problem is not there with local machine , it is there if i access it from remote machine only.have imported requires certificates also.

Comment: @java beginner  What i am saying is that the opening statement of your answer is a vulnerability: `In my application it is required that only certain pages need to be secured using SSL so i configured it `